# Migration from JSF to CDI - javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Class is not known to this context

Tags: java, jaxb, cdi

I have with migration from JSF annotation to CDI.
I changed `@ManagedBean` to `@Named` and package of SessionScoped from `javax.faces.bean` to `javax.enterprise.context`. When I start application and try to get on `antek.xhtml` I had following exception:

```
Error Rendering View[/html/antek.xhtml] javax.faces.FacesException: Could not retrieve value of component with path : {Component-Path : [Class: org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot,ViewId: /html/antek.xhtml][Class: javax.faces.component.html.HtmlOutputText,Id: pojo]}
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.RendererUtils.getValue(RendererUtils.java:347)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.RendererUtils.getStringValue(RendererUtils.java:295)
    ... 
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: /html/antek.xhtml @15,63 value="#{antekBean.pojo}": Error reading 'pojo' on type com.antek.gui.test.AntekBean_$$_javassist_5
    at com.sun.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:76)
    at javax.faces.component._DeltaStateHelper.eval(_DeltaStateHelper.java:243)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:71)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.RendererUtils.getValue(RendererUtils.java:343)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: com.antek.core.dto.AntekDto is not known to this context
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.createWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:175)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:70)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:128)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: com.antek.core.dto.AntekDto is not known to this context
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getBeanInfo(JAXBContextImpl.java:642)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.getBeanInfo(UnmarshallerImpl.java:568)
    at com.ibm.jtc.jax.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:353)
    ... 83 more
```

Of course before migration everything was ok.
I work on WebSphere Application Server 8.0.0.7.

Source codes from my project:
`AntekDto.java`

```
@XmlType // without that the same error is thrown
public class AntekDto implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String awesomeFiled;

    public String getAwesomeFiled() {
        return this.awesomeFiled;
    }
    public void setAwesomeFiled(final String awesomeFiled) {
        this.awesomeFiled = awesomeFiled;
    }
}
```

`AntekWebService.java`

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://antek.com/core")
public interface AntekWebService {
    @WebMethod(operationName = "getPojo")
    @RequestWrapper(className = "GetPojoRequestWrapper")
    @ResponseWrapper(className = "GetPojoResponseWrapper")
    AntekDto getPojo();
}
```

`AntekServiceImpl.java`

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.antek.testwebservice.AntekWebService", serviceName = "AntekService", targetNamespace = "http://antek.com/core")
public class AntekServiceImpl implements AntekWebService {
    @Override
    public AntekDto getPojo() {
        final AntekDto antekDto = new AntekDto();
        antekDto.setAwesomeFiled("some text for awesome field");
        return antekDto;
    }
}
```

`AntekBean.java`

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class AntekBean implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2307667354352709172L;

    @Produces
    @WebServiceRef(name = AntekService.SERVICE_PORT_NAME, value = AntekService.class)
    private transient AntekWebService antekWebService;

    public String getPojo() {
        return "<start>" + this.antekWebService.getPojo().getAwesomeFiled() + "<end>";
    }
}
```

`AntekService.java`

```
@WebServiceClient(name = AntekService.SERVICE_NAME, targetNamespace = AntekService.NAMESPACE, wsdlLocation = AntekService.WSDL_LOCATION)
public class AntekService extends Service {
    public static final String SERVICE_NAME = "AntekService";
    public static final String SERVICE_PORT_NAME = SERVICE_NAME + "Port";
    public static final String NAMESPACE = "http://antek.com/core";
    public static final String WSDL_LOCATION = "http://localhost:" + WebServiceProperties.PORT_NUMBER
            + "/ApplicationClientWS/" + SERVICE_NAME + "/" + SERVICE_NAME + ".wsdl";

    public AntekService(final URL wsdlLocation, final QName serviceName) {
        super(wsdlLocation, serviceName);
    }

    @WebEndpoint(name = AntekService.SERVICE_PORT_NAME)
    public final AntekWebService getAntekServicePort() {
        return super.getPort(new QName(NAMESPACE, SERVICE_PORT_NAME), AntekWebService.class);
    }
}
```

`beans.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>
```

`antek.xhtml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk">
    <head>
    <title>cdi</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Object: <h:outputText id="pojo" value="#{antekBean.pojo}" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Could someone please explain me why this exception is thrown?